# I want to know whether there is a default functionality for updating a django template from the server side based on an event

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, django, python-3.x

I am a beginner django developer. I am supposed to make an auction website. I have to update the template which shows the listing of the items and bids and I will have to update the template with latest bids each time a bidder makes one without having to refresh the page for each new update.

I have thought of querying the table each second and make ajax calls at the same intervals but I want to have real time updates without the extra overhead of polling and ajax calls each second, thus this question.

I am not looking for a specific piece of code to accomplish this, I just wanted to know whether there is any relevant package available to aid me in this, if not I'd request you to suggest me with a generic direction to accomplish this.

Answer (score 2):

[Django-channels](https://channels.readthedocs.io/en/stable/index.html) is one of the best package to do what you are looking for , It is new way for connecting Django backend to Django frontend.

Take a look [here](https://github.com/andrewgodwin/channels-examples) for examples